# How to fix the image in center using css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I`m using a bootstrap4 navbar, using navbar toggler icon in leftside and fixing a image at center by mx-auto it works but the image not center for whole navbar.

It takes center after the toggler icon, but I need the image want to be center for whole navigation bar and also toggler icon wants to be placed at left side .

How could I do this?

```
<a class="float-left">

     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"> 

     </span>

</a>

<img src="logo.png" class="mx-auto"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read:[stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
nav{
poasition:relative;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Pure code answers that offer no explanation are not very useful and generally end up being deleted.